# projecteuler problem 8 - unsure on what is wrong with my code

Tags: python, algorithm, project

> A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, a < b < c,
> for which,
>
> ```
> a^2 + b^2 = c^2
> ```
>
> For example, `3^2 + 4^2 = 9 + 16 = 25 = 5^2.`
>
> There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which a + b + c =
> 1000. Find the product `abc`.

above is the question. when i run my code it works and runs how i expect it to, but the programme always finishes without finding an answer. any advice on how to improve my code would be appreciated.

```py
for k in range (1,1000):
    c = 1000 - k 

    for i in range (1,c):
        b = c - i 
        c_sqr = c ** 2
        b_sqr = b ** 2 
        a = c - b 
        a_sqr = a ** 2

        if a_sqr + b_sqr == c_sqr:
            if a + b + c == 1000:
                product = a * b * c 
                print(f"{product} is the answer")
                exit()
            else:
                print("Pythagorean triplet!")
        else:
            josephmama = 11
            print("not a pythagorean triplet")
```

Comment: my question didnt post correctly - the k in range function is formatted and and indented correctly.

Comment: Those loops seem very convoluted. Why not loop `a` and `b` directly such that `b > a` and determine `c` from the difference to 1000?

Answer (score 1):

In your code `c < 1000` and `a + b == c` are invariants. The sum `(a + b + c) == 2 * c` requires that the longest side(hypotenuse) of the right triangle to be as long as the sum of the other sides, and there's no such numbers that satisfy it and so the `if` body never executes.

```
for a in range(1, 1000):
    for b in range(1, 1000):
        c = 1000 - (a + b)
        if (a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2):
            print(a * b * c)
            exit()
```

Comment: Where is `(a + b + c) == 2 * c` mentioned?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur, it's not explicitly mentioned it follows from the given expressions, i.e., ```b = c - i``` and ```a = c - b``` => ```a == i and b == c - i```, the problem requires ```a + b + c == 1000``` which is never fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

a is not always equal to c - b

by deriving b from c and a from c and b you are unnecessarily limiting the options of what b and a could be. Just loop through all combinations of a, b and c, add the constrains you have and you'll eventually get your triplet.

```
for a in range(1, 1000):
    for b in range(1, 1000):
        for c in range(1, 1000):
            if a+b+c == 1000:
                if a**2+b**2 == c**2:
                    if a < b:
                        if b < c:
                            print(f"My Triplet: a: {a}, b: {b}, c:{c}")
```

Comment: About the last comment: Yes, those are supposed to be natural numbers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).